# How to calculate the limiting resistor for an MCU's oscillator?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, crystal

I need some clarification on how to calculate the limiting resistor for the oscillator of an MCU. This:

[image]

I have read the application note of the manufacturer of the MCU (STM32), but it is not clear to me how to calculate that resistance value.

In my specific case, I have a STM32L476 MCU and as crystals I have an 830108288709 and an ECS-.327-12.5-34QS-TR.

I chose them almost randomly; they seem suitable for the application, but if you recommend me to change them there are no problems and I will use other components.

Comment: The LSE oscillator (32768 Hz) is difficult to probe, since it is very high impedance...a 'scope probe alters its operation. However, you might monitor the **LSE OUT** pin with a 'scope and see how fast it starts up from power-up. Anything faster than one second suggests R17 is too small. Anything slower than five seconds suggests R17 is on the high side and you're risking a non-oscillator.

Comment: Well, after looking at MCU docs and appnotes, what resistance values did you come up with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *how to calculate that resistance value*

The resistor is used for two reasons: -

- To create an extra bit of phase shift (with the output-side capacitor) to ensure the circuit oscillates successfully
- To limit the power into the crystal to prevent it exceeding the crystal's power rating (usually microwatts)

So, pick a crystal and read what the maximum power is for the crystal (in the data sheet) and make a simulation of the oscillator to see what power you get. It's power supply dependant so, ensure you take that into account.

You mention this part: ECS-.327-12.5-34QS-TR and, from it's [data sheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/122/ECX_34Q-938174.pdf) you'll see: -

[image]

Inside the red box are two parameters; the power drive level (0.5 μW maximum) and the effective series resistance (70 kΩ). So, given the power and the resistance, the voltage across the crystal at near series-resonance should be no higher than 187 mV RMS but, given that the effective series resistance is a maximum value (don't ask why they specified the maximum), the maximum voltage could be significantly less than 187 mV RMS. So, for this crystal, you might need several tens of kΩ for the external resistor mentioned in your question.

And, if you wanted to model the crystal, there's enough information on the image to do so. Your other crystal (the [830108288709](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/445/830108288709-2005336.pdf)) has a maximum drive level of 100 μW and an ESR of 20 Ω: -

[image]

I'm sure you can do the math now.

Comment: I understand the calculation you made, and I think I can do it for the other one as well. However, a value of tens of Kohms leaves me a little surprised because in all the diagrams I see around, this resistance is always very low (order of tens of ohms).https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32f769i-eval.html#overview
For example, in this official evaluation board of the MCU manufacturer (not same chip but same MCU Family), there are not even resistors on the oscillators.

Comment: @FedericoMassimi there is a resistor but, it's the natural internal series resistance of the gate the device uses. For low frequency crystals like 32,768 Hz, big value resistors are often used because the crystal part was originally designed for a wrist watch and, therefore they have to consume very little power to keep battery life good.

Answer (score 1):

If you have too high resistance the oscillator will not start reliably under all conditions.

If you have too low resistance you may exceed the maximum power dissipation specification of the crystal, causing premature aging, drift and even failure. This is more of a problem with tiny crystals that have uW maximum dissipation.

Usually manufacturers recommend using an (expensive) high-frequency [current probe](https://www.testequity.com/product/14175-2-CT6) to actually determine the crystal current and then calculate the dissipation from the maximum ESR figure in the crystal datasheet (or you can actually measure the crystal parameters with a (extremely expensive) network analyzer) to ensure that the drive power is in a sensible range.